# Why installation in some Android Devices does not set Open by Default Open supported links?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, android-deep-link

The deep link https://clevelink.github.io/details successfully opens my app in both Galaxy s6 with Android 7, and Samsung a52 with Android 13.

- assetlinks.json is accessible here: https://clevelink.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json
- Digital Asset Links API discovers and confirms the relationship between my deep link and my App (`io.github.clevelink`) [here](https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://clevelink.github.io&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls)
- Play Console deep links confirms "*All links working. Users will go directly to your app*"

[image]

However when I install my App release in emulator Pixel API 33 Android 33, through `flutter run --release`, it does NOT include the aforementioned URL and has **0 verified links**:

[image]

On the other, it is installed and well configured for both Galaxy S6 and Samsung a52, as shown next:

[image]
[image]

**Why installation for some Android Devices does not include the verified links?**

This demo App source code is publicly available in https://github.com/fmcarvalho/clevelink

Comment: is your well-known file set correctly on your server, your manifest declaration? It can take a few seconds to few minutes for Google to auto register your deep links. Package name and SHA keys should match as well.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla It is is everything correctly configured. Otherwise, no Android device would open the deep link for my App. It works fine for devices such as emulator Pixel 33, or Samsung Galaxy S6, and others. Only in a few devices my App  stays without the option Open by Default Open supported links, after installation. And I cannot understand why the installation stays like that for such devices?

Comment: Since Android 12+, web links truly needs the well-known as previous versions didn't enforced it. If your issue with Android 12+? Are all the links added correctly? The issue is just on emulators and/or physical devices? Play Services up to date? Device versions? Have you waited a few minutes with correct internet connection?

Comment: I answered a similar question here that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77403722/6723646

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla All the links and assetlinks.json are well configured and available. I have updated OP with additional URLs and you can check by yourself those links are correct. My question is not about the availability of those links, but about the way my App is installed by default, instead.

Comment: @rhpekarek I added additional information on OP showing that assetlinks.json is accessible and correctly configured, including right sha256 fingerprint. My question is not about the availability of those links, but about the way my App is installed by default, instead.

Comment: running as --release doesn't make the build a release one as the signature being used is the default debug one and I'm not expecting a debug app to auto approve your deep links on newer versions of Android. Are you also including the default android SHA fingerprint for the debug? But, again, don't expect that behavior as I always manually enable those deep links while I develop.

Comment: Yes, android SHA fingerprint for the debug is included.